# How to create namebased object-array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Currently, i try to check out `TypeScript`.

On my old `JavaScript`-Source i have a simple namebased Array-Object for a EventListener:

```js
let _events  = {};

this.addEventListener = function addEventListener(name, callback) {
  if(typeof(_events[name]) == 'undefined') {
   _events[name] = [];
  }
  
  _events[name].push(callback);
 };
 
 this.fireEvent = function fireEvent() {
  let fired = false;
  let args = new Array();
  let name = arguments[0];
  
  if(typeof(_events[name]) == 'undefined') {
   return;
  }
  
  for(var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
   args.push(arguments[index]);
  }
 
  _events[name].forEach(function onEvent(event) {
   fired = true;
   event.apply(this, args);
  }.bind(this));
  
  return fired;
 };
```

How i can create the same method in TypeScript?

Here is a Sample result:

```
{
    "init": [callback, callback, callback],
    "otherEvent": [callback, callback]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the same using TypeScript and some of the latest ES6 features. For example, instead of using an object `_events` as a key/value map you could use an ES6 Map:

```
class EventManager {

    private _events: Map<string, Array<Function>>;

    public addEventListener(name: string, callback: Function) {
        if(this._events.has(name) === false) {
            this._events.set(name, [callback]);
        } else {
            const previosCallbacks = this._events.get(name);
            previosCallbacks.push(callback);
            this._events.set(name, previosCallbacks);
        }
    }

    public fireEvent(name: string, ...args: any[]) {

        let fired = false;

        if (this._events.has(name) === false) {
            return;
        }

        this._events.get(name).forEach((cb) => {
            fired = true;
            cb(...args);
        });

        return fired;
    }

}
```

Comment: When i export as a `Map`, these class will not found after compiling (using `ES5`/`ES2015`). I had already try to use a Map like you..

Comment: If you are trying to run the code in an old version of nodejs or web browser Map will not be available but you can use a Shim. Like corejs for example https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#map

Comment: If your problem is a compilation error because `Map` is not defined you will need to use `"target": "es5"` and also `"lib": ["es6"]` in` tsconfig.json`

Comment: Changing of `target` or `lib` won't solve the problem.